# Venn diagram for $\{1, \{\{2\},3\}\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider this set:

[image]

The correct way to write is:

$$U=\{1;2;3\}, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\      A=\{2;3\}, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\ B=\{2\}$$

I was writing it wrong, like this $$ U = \{1,\{\{2\};3\}\},\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,A=\{\{2\},3\},\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,B=\{\{2\}\} $$

I think this writting is wrong because in this case, A and B will not be subsets of the set U (For example, 3 is element of A and 3 is not element of U)

So, whats the correct Venn diagram to represent the set $$ U = \{1,\{\{2\};3\}\}$$?

Comment: You should always use $\color{red},$, there's no for $\color{red};$.

Comment: $U$ is a set with two elements, namely $1$ and $\{\{2\},3\}$.

Comment: Yes, as Git Gud says the symbol ; has no meaning in this context: you should only use the commas. Colons (:) are also not used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $U=\{1,\{\{2\},3\}\}$, $A=\{\{2\},3\}$, $B=\{\{2\}\}$, then the Venn diagram below is correct.

[image: Venn]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This would be the venn diagram of the set U={1,{{2},3}}

U only has two elements, the element 1 and the element which is the set {{2},3}.

Elements of a set can also be sets.